# how can i get value ??in python and sqlite

Tags: python, sqlite

i want to get each 'cursor_1' value.
  Make code like this,

```
cursor_1 = conn.execute("SELECT cost from test where name like 'fish'")
for row in cursor_1:
print "cost = ", row[0]
data = conn.execute("SELECT cost from test where name like 'fish'").fetchall()
```

I think data value is '[3900,3900,2500,3800]'

,but the result is

```
[('3900',), ('3900',), (' 2500',), (' 3800',)]
```

how can i get data like '[3900,3900,2500,3800]?

Answer (score 0):

each element represent a row since you used `fetchall`. just map the first element like so

```
map(lambda x: x[0], data)
```

or

```
[x[0] for x in data]
```

Comment: or, more efficiently, ``[item[0] for item in data]``.